# Excel Lookup Table and Match Values Based on Row Difference

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a daily dashboard that I am building out where I need to multiply a daily intake by a specific value that changes once the daily intake goes over a specific tier number. The challenge that I currently face is that I am unable to multiply the correct tier multiplier when the tier amount is hit within a specific day. This means that the higher tier multiplier is being spread across all of the daily intakes for that day rather than the difference that ended up in the higher tier within that day. Any help would be great! Thank you.

Provided is a working example:

1) I have a table that has the multipliers (Investment) and the start and end tier.

[image: Investment Table]

2) Intake tier hit on 11/12. As you would see if you added up the numbers, 11/11 was 464 and 11/12 was 506, which means that 11 of the 42 intake on 11/12 should be multiplied by $150 rather than $200, which is not happening with my current formula

[image: Intake tier]

3) Multiplying the intake amounts by the table values based on the presence of "2nd Tier" in the table above `=IF(E6="",$V$3*$D6,$V$4*D6)`

[image: Investment tier]

Comment: If hitting the 2nd tier during the day in question doesn't count, then have your formula look at the total as of the **previous** day rather than the current day.

Comment: Assuming the Intake of 29 is in D2, enter this formula in the first cell under Investment and fill down:  Investment = `IF(SUM(D$2:D2)>475,IF(E2="",475*150+(SUM(D$2:D2)-475)*200,D2*200),D2*150)`

Comment: @Bandersnatch thank you for your solution, but I believe there might be an issue with the formula. The `475*150` is off because it is saying 475 intake + the difference of 475 and the sum up to this point

Comment: @cphill, you're correct.  I'll revise the formula and post it in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the revised answer.  The table below shows the investment for November 12 calculated correctly.

[image]

The formula in F2 is:

```
=IF(SUM(D$2:E2)>475,IF(E1="",50*(SUM(D$2:D2)-475)+150*D2,200*D2),150*D2)
```

Most of it is straightforward.  If the running sum of Column D (SUM(D$2:Dnn) is less than 475, then the Investment is 150*Dnn.  If the running sum is greater than 475 *and* the previous row of Column E is not blank, then the Investment is 200*Dnn.

In the case where the running sum is greater than 475 and the previous row of Column E *is* blank (November 12) then part of the intake is multiplied by 200 and the remainder is multiplied by 150.

The portion of the intake to be multiplied by 200 is the excess of the running sum over 475 - this is just the running sum less 475. So that part of the Investment is `200*(SUM(C$2:Cnn)-475)`. The remainder of the amount in Column D is Dnn minus that excess amount or `Dnn-(SUM(C$2:Cnn)-475)`, and this is the portion to be multiplied by 150. Representing the running sum as "Sum", the total investment is:

```
200*(Sum - 475) + 150*(Dnn-(Sum-475))
```

This expression could be used in the formula, but it can be simplified.  Simplifying gives:

```
200*Sum - 200*475 + 150*Dnn - 150*Sum + 150*475
50*Sum - 50*475 + 150*Dnn
50*(Sum-475) + 150*Dnn
```

and this is the "value if true" in the inner IF() statement:

```
50*(SUM(D$2:D2)-475)+150*D2
```

I hope this helps and please excuse the false start in my comment above.

Comment: Great explanation and appreciate the simplification. This has been a huge help to my day to day work. Thank you!